# AngularJS: Function with promise and non-promise data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have a function that has data which is a combination of promise data and simple math values. Here's the function :

```
_getTotalPrice = function() {

            var price = 0;
            // Simple Math data.
            // Calculate price for channels first. 
            price = price + ( num_channels - 5 )*( 4);


            var themepacks = cart.themepacks;
            if(themepacks) {
                angular.forEach(themepacks, function(pack, index) {

                // data coming from a service
                channelFactory.getThemePack(pack).then(function(result) {
                    price = price + Number(result.packPriceAmt);
                    console.log("price", price);
                  });
              });
            }

          console.log(" Total price", price);
          return price; 
 };
```

At the time of page load, the value of `Total price` and `price` is different. It is because the `price` is loaded after promise is resolved. How can I wait till the promise is resolved before returning the value? Do I create another promise within this function?

Comment: Did you had a look at $q ?  Refer http://www.codeducky.org/q-serial/ or anyother example.

Comment: You can't *wait* to return a value within function. It is either returned with `return` or `undefined` is returned as implicit return. Return a promise that returns a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function must itself return a promise for the total price which is dependent on all (`all`) of the created promises' resolutions.

First, a little factoring will help clear it up:

```
// return a promise for a theme pack price
function priceOfPack(pack) {
    return channelFactory.getThemePack(pack).then(function(result) {
        return Number(result.packPriceAmt);
    });
}
```

This makes clearer the idea that we're going to collect a set of prices asynchronously.  Now the loop is simpler...

```
_getTotalPrice = function() {
    var themepacks = cart.themepacks || [];
    var promises = [];
    angular.forEach(themepacks, function(pack, index) {
        promises.push(priceOfPack(pack));
    });
    var basePrice = (num_channels - 5) * 4;

    // when all promises are resolved, they will be with an array of prices
    return $q.all(promises).then(function(result) {
        return result.reduce((a, b) => { a + b }, basePrice);
    });
}
```

The caller must realize that the new function returns a promise and change accordingly, so...

```
_getTotalPrice().then(function(result) {
    // result is the totalPrice
});
```

Comment: what about `if(!themepacks)`?

Comment: @charlietfl, yes, i didn't supply the entire _getTotalPrice method.  Just the bits pertinent to promises.

Comment: guessing OP doesn't know they need another promise returned for other condition

Comment: @charlietfl, good point.  edited to include a complete function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
_getTotalPrice = function() {

            var price = 0;
            // Simple Math data.
            // Calculate price for channels first. 
            price = price + ( num_channels - 5 )*( 4);


            var themepacks = cart.themepacks;
            if(themepacks) {
                angular.forEach(themepacks, function(pack, index) {

                // data coming from a service
                return channelFactory.getThemePack(pack).then(function(result) {
                    price = price + Number(result.packPriceAmt);
                    return $q.when(price);
                  });
              });
            }
            else{
              return $q.when(price);
            }
 };

 _getTotalPrice().then(function(price){
   console.log(price);
 });
```

It'll be async function.

Comment: return inside forEach does nothing and you need array of promise created by that loop. Solution will not work

Comment: oh, i missed that he has forEach

so instead u need to use this:

return $q.all(promises).then(function(results) {
                    angular.forEach(results, function(result){
price = price + Number(result.packPriceAmt);
                    
});
return $q.when(price);
});

Comment: i am a she not a he.